# One column or separate columns for extra data - mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I was thinking what if I have a table with columns for meta_description (varchar 300), meta_tags (varchar 300), and meta_title (varchar 200)... can I "join" all this columns just into one column "extra_information" (longtext) and save here the same information but maybe in JSON format?

Is this convenient or not and why :)?

This fields are not very important for me, I will never make any query to search or sort the results trough this information. The metatags for example are only a comma separated text I don't need to do some kind of relation table on this.

What I want to know is this will save space on my database or will be working a little bit faster, or things like that... But if you tell me that have 5 columns instead of just one is the same for MySQL of course I will have the 5 columns...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's hard to say 100% without knowing what you'll do with the data, but if you ever hope to select based on description or tag or title you should leave them in separate columns. Additionally, if `meta_tags` is a list of values it should be in a related table - MySQL has the [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function to help you find values in a comma-delimited string, but it will be very slow if you tables get large.

Comment: You can use CONCAT to group your column as a single result: `SELECT CONCAT(meta_description, meta_tags , meta_title) as extra_information ... `
For the next part of the question it isn't clear enough for me ...

Comment: Why not store everything in JSON? No need for a database at all? Once you figured out why that won't work, you can apply the same answer in smaller scale to your question.

Comment: If you don't want to search the information from within the database then just store the json string. Otherwise keep it normalized, and use (for instance) PHP's json_encode/decode functions to take it back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

The answer boils down on: Does MySQL have to work with your data?

If all date is concatenated in one column, be it as JSON or comma-seperated or what not, it is nearly off limits for any MySQL operation. You can surely `SELECT` it, but it is very hard to search, group or sort by anything inside that column. So, it you are absolutly sure MySQL soes never have to see the data itself and will only return some column with data in it, go for it.
Benefits are that the table structure does not have to be changed because your data changes. and column structure is very clean

if you need to filter, sort, group or do whatever operation on it within a SQL query, leave it in seperate columns.

Comment: +1. I concur. If MySQL will *never* have to perform operations on the stored data (other than storing the entire value, and retrieving the entire value), then a single column would be fine. (As if MySQL sees that column as one chunk of data, as if it was a .jpg image, for example.) But if MySQL needs to perform operations on the data, then you are certainly going to want the individual parts that MySQL needs to operate on stored in separate columns.